# Is there a shortcut for collecting commits since the beginning of the branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When doing an interactive rebase on a feature branch, I usually want to pull only the commits that are new in that branch into the rebase, which means I need to first check my log, count the commits, and specify `git rebase HEAD~n --interactive` where `n` is the number of commits.

Is there any shortcut command to just collect the commits I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't even have to worry about "commit counting" to rebase a feature branch onto a "main" branch.

Say you have a feature branch `f1` created from `master` some time ago. If you later want to rebase `f1` on `master`, assuming your current branch is `f1`, you simply have to run `git rebase master`.

Git knows when `f1`and `master` diverged and can thus know which commits must be rebased onto `master`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do when I pull changes into master, but never thought about doing it that way for an interactive rebase for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git merge <feature-branch> <origin branch>`  This will give the latest SHA that is common for both branchs.  Then you will be able to do the interactive rebase from that commit.

Comment: I was looking more for a 1 step process I could replace `HEAD~n` with in my rebase command.